# What does it mean: a six-pack was how you bought your beer?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I want to understand what is the context of quoting  "a six-pack was how you bought your beer"

> At 44, I am old enough to remember when reconstruction was something
>   you read about in history class, when a muffin top was something
>   delicious you ate at the bakery, a six-pack was how you bought your
>   beer, camel toe was something one might glimpse at the zoo, a
>   Brazilian was someone from the largest country in South America and
>   terms like thigh gap and bikini bridge would be met with blank looks.

Comment: http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/15/opinion/sunday/from-sports-illustrated-the-latest-body-part-for-women-to-fix.html?WT.mc_id=2015-APRIL-INYT-INTL_REG_ENG-0407-0411&WT.mc_ev=click&ad-keywords=IntlAudDev&_r=0 it is from thie article .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author was thinking of her past experience. Once upon a time, not so many years ago, mentioning the word **"six-pack"** would make most people think of a six-pack of beer, i.e. buying beer in a pack of six (either bottles or cans):

[image: a six-pack of beer bottles] [image: a six-pack of beer cans]

<sup>Images retrieved from: http://pixgood.com/six-pack-of-beer.html, http://pixgood.com/six-pack-of-beer-cans.html</sup>

Nowadays, mentioning **"six-pack"** will make most people think of this:

[image: A man lifts his shirt up to expose his well-developed abdominal muscles]

<sup>Image retrieved from: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sixpack_germanuncut77_flickr.jpg</sup>

So, *At 44, I am old enough to remember when [...] a **six-pack was how you bought your beer**, [...],* is pretty much a sentence reminiscing about the old days the writer can remember. It's the old days when people still thought of *six-pack* as beer rather than [abs (or abdomens or rectus abdominis muscle)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectus_abdominis_muscle) like most of us would think of these days.

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, welcome to ELL!

Comment: the man shows his muscle ^_^